# Faster way to change user inputs into int in a list?

Tags: python

Currently, I have this code:

```
mylist = []
t1,t2 = input().split(' ')
t1 = int(t1)
t2 = int(t2)
mylist.append(t1)
mylist.append(t2)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit a previously created list

You can use `map()` and `list.extend()`:

```py
my_list = []
my_list.extend(map(int, input().split()))  # .split(' ') can lead to unexpected behavior
print(my_list)
# >>> 123 132542
# [123, 132542]
```

> map(func, *iterables) –> map object
>
> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each of the iterables. Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

This solution is resilient to multiple spaces between integers and can handle an undetermined amount of integers.

#### Create a new list:

```py
my_list = list(map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: Already edited but I prefer using the same context as the OP

Comment: actually, my t1 and t2 are coordinates, so they need to be appended into the list as a list, is there a way to do so since .append doesn't work with map()?

Comment: This isn't in you question, consider edit it.
You can do this: `my_list.append(list(map(...))`, but in this case, I think the list comprehension is better.
If I missunderstood your comment: don't use `.append()`, use `.extend()` instead

Comment: print([tuple(map(int, s.replace('(','').replace(')','').split(','))) for s in input().split()]). If you pass (1,2) (3,4) as input it returns [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
print([int(n) for n in input().split()])
```